# Iterate through deep nested hash by using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration, nested-loops, traversal

I'm trying to iterate through a nested object to retrieve a specific object identified by a string. In the sample object below, the identifier string is the "label" property. I don't know how to iterate down through the tree to return the appropriate object.

My Ruby and Rails versions are pretty old.
**Ruby - 1.9.3
Rails - 3.0.9**

`

```
company_tree = {
  label: 'Autos',
  subs: [
    {
      label: 'SUVs',
      subs: []
    },
    {
      label: 'Trucks',
      subs: [
        {
          label: '2 Wheel Drive',
          subs: []
        },
        {
          label: '4 Wheel Drive',
          subs: [
            {
              label: 'Ford',
              subs: []
            },
            {
              label: 'Chevrolet',
              subs: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Sedan',
      subs: []
    }
  ]
}
```

`

I tried using below code. But I didn't worked. It only return the second array only. It won't go beyond that.

`

```
data = JSON.parse(requestData)

data['company_tree']['subs'].each do |element|
    puts "element=> #{element['subs']}"
end
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support, I found out the solution

```
    def iterate(i)
        if i.is_a?(Hash)
            i.each do |k, v|
                if v.is_a?(Hash) || v.is_a?(Array)
                    iterate(v)
                else
                    puts("k is #{k}, value is #{v}")
                end
            end
        end
        if i.is_a?(Array)
            i.each do |v|
                iterate(v)
            end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the `company_tree` variable like described in your question, you can use recursion to iterate over each element and all of its subs. This is the code I made and I will explain it a bit further below

```rb
def destruct_tree(element)
  puts "#{element[:label]} with subs #{element[:subs]}"
  element[:subs].each do |sub|
    destruct_tree sub
  end
end

destruct_tree company_tree
```

You give the function the `company_tree` element. Then it prints its label and subs. Then it iterates over all the subs and passes them to the same function again. Which will intern print their label and subs and run through all their subs again.

I hope this made sense

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the hash like below:

```
def iterate_through(company_tree)
  puts "#{company_tree[:label]} => #{company_tree[:subs]}"
  company_tree[:subs].each do |sub|
    iterate_through(sub)
  end
end

iterate_through(company_tree)


Output:

Autos => [{:label=>"SUVs", :subs=>[]}, {:label=>"Trucks", :subs=>[{:label=>"2 Wheel Drive", :subs=>[]}, {:label=>"4 Wheel Drive", :subs=>[{:label=>"Ford", :subs=>[]}, {:label=>"Chevrolet", :subs=>[]}]}]}, {:label=>"Sedan", :subs=>[]}]
SUVs => []
Trucks => [{:label=>"2 Wheel Drive", :subs=>[]}, {:label=>"4 Wheel Drive", :subs=>[{:label=>"Ford", :subs=>[]}, {:label=>"Chevrolet", :subs=>[]}]}]
2 Wheel Drive => []
4 Wheel Drive => [{:label=>"Ford", :subs=>[]}, {:label=>"Chevrolet", :subs=>[]}]
Ford => []
Chevrolet => []
Sedan => []
```